# Can't convert expression to float?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the 9 nonlinear equations with python, but the output is error. I have posted the code as following: 
The code has solved P1 P2 P3 A1 A2 A3 as [x,y,z] coordinates number stored. I am trying to use the these positions to find out the last three points (x1, y1, z1),(x2, y2, z2),(x3, y3, z3).

```
# For symbolic calculations use sympy
import sympy
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos,sin

###Set up B1 point 
x1, y1, z1 = sympy.symbols('x1 y1 z1')

###Set up B2 point 
x2, y2, z2 = sympy.symbols('x2 y2 z2')

### Set up B3 point 
x3, y3, z3 = sympy.symbols('x3 y3 z3')

# Each lower arm has length Lc, this is length for A B  
Lc = 3.0 

#Define second points into seperate variables 
a11 = A1[0]
a12 = A1[1]
a13 = A1[2]
a21 = A2[0]
a22 = A2[1]
a23 = A2[2]
a31 = A3[0]
a32 = A3[1]
a33 = A3[2]

##Constrain for Bar AB
eq1 = (x1 - A1[0])**2 + (y1 - A1[1])**2 + (z1 - A1[2])**2 - Lc**2 
eq2 = (x2 - A2[0])**2 + (y2 - A2[1])**2 + (z2 - A2[2])**2 - Lc**2 
eq3 = (x3 - A3[0])**2 + (y3 - A3[1])**2 + (z3 - A2[2])**2 - Lc**2 




### Length for plate B points
Ld = 0.2

##Constrain for plate B points
eq4 = (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2 - z1)**2 - Ld**2 
eq5 = (x3 - x1)**2 + (y3 - y1)**2 + (z3 - z1)**2 - Ld**2 
eq6 = (x3 - x2)**2 + (y3 - y2)**2 + (z3 - z2)**2 - Ld**2 

###Vectors for points P and points A

Upa1 = [A1[0] - P1[0], A1[1] - P1[1], A1[2] - P1[2] ]
Upa2 = [A2[0] - P2[0], A2[1] - P2[1], A2[2] - P2[2] ]
Upa3 = [A3[0] - P3[0], A3[1] - P3[1], A3[2] - P3[2] ]

###Vectors for points A and B
Uab1 = [x1 - A1[0], y1 - A1[1], z1 - A1[2]]
Uab2 = [x2 - A2[0], y2 - A2[1], z2 - A2[2]]
Uab3 = [x3 - A3[0], y3 - A3[1], z3 - A3[2]]
eq7 = np.dot(np.cross(Upa1, Uab1),u1)
eq8 = np.dot(np.cross(Upa2, Uab2),u2)
eq9 = np.dot(np.cross(Upa3, Uab3),u3)

###Using Scipy to solve equations 
def equations(z):
  x1 = z[0]
  y1 = z[1]
  z1 = z[2]
  x2 = z[3]
  y2 = z[4]
  z2 = z[5]
  x3 = z[6]
  y3 = z[7]
  z3 = z[8]

  F = empty((9))
  F[0] = (x1 - A1[0])**2 + (y1 - A1[1])**2 + (z1 - A1[2])**2 - Lc**2
  F[1] = (x2 - A2[0])**2 + (y2 - A2[1])**2 + (z2 - A2[2])**2 - Lc**2 
  F[2] = (x3 - A3[0])**2 + (y3 - A3[1])**2 + (z3 - A2[2])**2 - Lc**2 
  F[3] = (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2 - z1)**2 - Ld**2 
  F[4] = (x3 - x1)**2 + (y3 - y1)**2 + (z3 - z1)**2 - Ld**2 
  F[5] = (x3 - x2)**2 + (y3 - y2)**2 + (z3 - z2)**2 - Ld**2 
  F[6] = np.dot(np.cross(Upa1, Uab1),u1)
  F[7] = np.dot(np.cross(Upa2, Uab2),u2)
  F[8] = np.dot(np.cross(Upa3, Uab3),u3)
  return F    

zGuess = [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]
z = fsolve(equations, zGuess)
```

The output is as following:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-fbac9f95877a> in <module>()
----> 1 z = fsolve(equations, zGuess)

/Users/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, epsfcn, factor, diag)
144                'diag': diag}
145 
--> 146     res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
147     if full_output:
148         x = res['x']

/Users/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
210     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
211         args = (args,)
--> 212     shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
213     if epsfcn is None:
214         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

/Users/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
 24 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
 25                 output_shape=None):
---> 26     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
 27     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
 28         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

<ipython-input-12-951ec1513690> in equations(z)
 18     F[4] = (x3 - x1)**2 + (y3 - y1)**2 + (z3 - z1)**2 - Ld**2
 19     F[5] = (x3 - x2)**2 + (y3 - y2)**2 + (z3 - z2)**2 - Ld**2
---> 20     F[6] = np.dot(np.cross(Upa1, Uab1),u1)
 21     F[7] = np.dot(np.cross(Upa2, Uab2),u2)
 22     F[8] = np.dot(np.cross(Upa3, Uab3),u3)

/Users/j/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.pyc in __float__(self)
237         if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1]:
238             raise TypeError("can't convert complex to float")
--> 239         raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
240 
241     def __complex__(self):

TypeError: can't convert expression to float

    TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Comment: Can you post enough code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the exception, and if possible, show where your data (e.g. `A`, `Lc`, and the various `UpaX` and `UabX` variables) are coming from, at least enough to see their types. Probably something is not the type you expect, leading to the exception you're getting. You may also want to add some tags, at least `numpy`, maybe others (`scypy` maybe?).

Comment: @jhpratt, I have added more detailed comments here. Hope this can provide you enough informations. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Blckknght have added more detailed comments here. Hope this can provide you enough informations. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `NameError: name 'A1' is not defined`

Comment: @ArndtJonasson A1 A2 A3 and P1 P2 P3 are defined previously. They are coordinates for the first 6 points.

Comment: So why not include them?

Comment: If you use `empty` this way instead: `F = np.empty((9), 'object')`, you get further, but instead get "minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.". Maybe you can find out why.

Comment: The 'object' things was a false track, I think. It looks like the problem is that you should work with numbers in `equations`, not symbols. I think you should recalculate Uab1 etc. in `equations` after x1 etc. have been fetched - the connection between `x1` in the global value of Uab1, and the `x1` in `equations` is only in our minds, because they have the same name.